# The [FILE] refers to a location that is unavailable. How do I delete the file?

Tags: windows-7

Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

A file on my computer refuses to be deleted. I'm not sure what the problem is. I've searched a few answers elsewhere but I'm not trying to "redirect the pathway" or anything like that. I just want the folder gone. It won't even let me rename it. Any help would be appreciated. I'm on windows 7 by the way.

Comment: Is the file on a USB drive? Can you find that drive?  I looked at the message: Can you see the folder in Windows Explorer?  If so, you can try Unlocker 1.92 to delete it. I use this.

Comment: I assume the issue is that the file ends in a "." and Explorer doesn't care for it.  You could try deleting it from a command prompt using the command/path: 
`del "\\?\C:\users\Austen\Desktop\The Notorious B.I.G."`